# What is the use `-d` in Perl script?

Tags: perl

What does the `-d` in the following piece of code:

```
foreach my $filename (@files) {
        my $filepath = $dir.$filename;
        next if -d $filepath;
        function1();
}
```

Comment: If you have `perldoc` installed, typing `perldoc -f function` will show you the documentation for `function`, e.g. `perldoc -f -d` takes you to the documentation for the [file test functions](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a short form for

```
if (-d $filepath) {
    next;
}
```

Where `-d $filepath` is a test if `$filepath` is a directory.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html for a full list of file tests.

Answer (score 4):

[`-d`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) tests if `$filepath` is a directory.

All such file tests are documented at [`perldoc -X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html):

> - `-X FILEHANDLE`
> - `-X EXPR`
> - `-X DIRHANDLE`
> - `-X`
>
>   A file test, where X is one of the letters listed below. This unary operator takes one argument, either a filename, a filehandle, or a dirhandle, and tests the associated file to see if something is true about it. If the argument is omitted, tests `$_`, except for `-t`, which tests STDIN. Unless otherwise documented, it returns `1` for true and `''` for false. If the file doesn't exist or can't be examined, it returns [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) and sets `$!` (errno). Despite the funny names, precedence is the same as any other named unary operator. The operator may be any of:
>
>   ```
>   ...
>   -f  File is a plain file.
>   -d  File is a directory.
>   ...
>   ```

Answer (score 2):

It checks for the directory...

A short example to check that

```
$somedir = "c:/windows";
if (-d $somedir) {
    print "$somedir exists";
} else {
    print "$somedir does not exist!";
}
```

Also check the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) for other such cases

```
-f  File is a plain file.
-d  File is a directory.
-l  File is a symbolic link.
-p  File is a named pipe (FIFO), or Filehandle is a pipe.
-S  File is a socket.
-b  File is a block special file.
-c  File is a character special file.
-t  Filehandle is opened to a tty.
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, `next if -d $filepath;` means "if this file is a directory, run the next iteration of the loop", which effectively skips the call of *function1* for that file. In short, it is a way of applying *function1* only to files which are NOT directories.